# How should I separate these functionalities into individual cases when they are interrelated?

Tags: laravel, testing

Say I want to test a upload functionality.

1. Users can upload multiple files.
2. Files are grouped by date and put in folders with date as name. E.x. 2018-06-04, 2018-06-03....
3. Users can only upload certain files, e.x. jpeg, pdf...

Should I test them separately or group them together and test in one go? While testing case 1, case 2 is also included in the logic, right? If I test case 3, case 1 and case 2 will also be included in the logic. If I test them together in one case, the test case seems too fat.

If I don't include the logic of case 2 while writing case 1, the whole test will eventually fail because the files are not group by date.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

ideally each test should test only one feature. this way:

1. when requirements change, you will have to change only one test
2. your live documentation (tests) will be more specific and easier to understand

> If I test case 3, case 1 and case 2 will also be included in the logic

not really. if you test if user can upload only jpg, you don't care where files will be saved. you just need to test that user can select only specific extensions and that server will reject others. you don't even need to include the file saving component in the test.

another thing is having some helper function that will prepare data for upload and will be reused by most tests